# Preserve indentation, HTML5 shorthand in editor

Tags: tinymce, editor, html5

I know there are other questions about tinyMCE, but this one is a little different. Let's say I create an unordered list that drops the closing li tags. I also have class attributes that I don't want to wrap in double quotes. This will be fine when I'm in the text editor, but when I switch to visual, TinyMCE will automatically add quotes and closing tags.

Is there a way to prevent this?

Also, even the text editor forces html indentation and I would like to avoid this as well.

Comment: Just a comment, but why? Single or double quotes make literally no difference, last `li` not wrapped is just invalid HTML, etc.

Comment: html5 doesn't need any quotes unless you have a string with more than one word. so class=myclass is fine. Also, you don't need closing li tags anymore, and I leave them out because it makes it easier to write them without nesting errors. I understand why TinyMCE wants to correct broken HTML, but if my HTML is actually valid, I would like it to stay the way I prefer to write it.

Comment: Didn't know about them being optional, thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are using the wrong software ;) wordpress is not really designed nor should it be used as an html editor.

If for whatever reason you need some concrete HTML format you should either use a shortcode to generate it or create a page template to be used in the places where it is needed.